# CodenameOne: automatically convert a theme file (theme.res) to CSS

Tags: css, codenameone

Cascading Stylesheet Support for Codename One is possible thanks to the [library cn1-css](https://github.com/shannah/cn1-css).

My question is about the conversion of a theme file (theme.res) to the equivalent CSS code. Is it possible automatically? If yes, what about the images incorporated in the theme file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It's only CSS to theme and not the other way around.

You can work with images from file system to a multi-image using the approach highlighted here: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/using-css-to-import-images.html

Comment: Thank you for the link! You wrote: «No. It's only theme to CSS and not the other way around»... maybe do you mean «It's only CSS to theme»?

Comment: Thanks, yes I fixed that